# Ordenar resultados de una consulta a MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero ordernar los resultados de mi consulta de manera que se muestre en primer lugar el último registro que se hizo.

Mi consulta es la siguiente:

```php
$re= $conexion->query("select productos_venta.*, productos.nombre  
                from productos_venta  inner join productos on productos_venta.id_producto = productos.id 
                where  productos_venta.id_venta = ".$f['id'])or die($conexion->error);
```

Imagen Referencial.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega un `ORDER BY DESC laColumnaPorLaQueQuieresOrdenar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A falta de los nombres de tus columnas, solo te puedo ayudar diciendo que debes usar un [`ORDER BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html). Por ejemplo si tu columna se llama `creacion` y se encuentra en `productos_venta` tendrías algo como esto:

```php
$re = $conexion->query("SELECT
    productos_venta.*,
    productos.nombre
FROM
    productos_venta
INNER JOIN
    productos ON productos_venta.id_producto = productos.id
WHERE
    productos_venta.id_venta = {$f['id']}
ORDER BY
    productos_venta.creacion DESC")or die($conexion->error);
```

También considera el uso de [sintaxis compleja (o de llaves)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) para tener una cadena más limpia y evitar el exceso de concatenaciones que pueden ser un problema de legibilidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió mucho